# How to return the same type as a function was called with?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am writing a function (typescript in a node.js application) that performs a parse-like process on array-like data (it would need `slice()`, `length` and the index operator `[]`).

I've defined a `type` that can be any of the required types, and a delimiter that is marked off the first element in the array/buffer.

This all works, but it requires a cast back to the original type once the function returns, ideally I would not want to perform the cast, I'd like the function to return the same type as the `buffer` argument, while maintaining all the same typescript checking in the function for the range of input types.

```
export type BufferLike<T> = Buffer | string | T[];

export function Parse<T>(buffer: BufferLike<T>, delim: typeof buffer[0]) {
    let result: typeof buffer[] = [];
    let idx = 0, i = 0;
    // content not material...
    result.push(buffer.slice(buffer[i] == delim ? idx : i));
    return result;
}
```

In use...

```
// creates error
// Type 'BufferLike<string>[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
const v1: string[] = Parse("121212", "2");

// compiles
const v2: string[] = <string[]>Parse("121212", "2");
```

I've tried a custom `interface`, but the results are pretty much as above.

```
export interface Splittable<T> {
    slice(idx: number, len?: number) : Splittable<T> // return same type as the class/interface
    //slice(idx: number, len?: number) : T[]
    [idx: number] : T // element access
    readonly length: number
}
```

How can I, or would I, define the function signature for `Parse`, such that I can have the return type be the same as the argument provided by the client, and still maintain the type checking?

Comment: You mean `Parse` instead of `BufferSplit`, right?

Comment: And `let idx, i = 0;` is confusing because `idx` is `undefined` there.  I'm looking for a [mcve] here so it would be nice to fix that to, e.g., `let idx = 0, i = 0;`

Comment: @jcalz, correct, fixed the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to be using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) as the return type of `splice()` in `Splittable<T>`:

```
export interface Splittable<T> {
  slice(idx: number, len?: number): this;
  [idx: number]: T
  readonly length: number
}
```

This is saying that calling `slice()` on an object whose type is a subtype of `Splittable<T>` will return an object of that same subtype.

Then you want `Parse` to be generic in `S`, the particular subtype of `Splittable<T>` you're getting, as well as the `T` of the delimiter:

```
export function Parse<S extends Splittable<T>, T>(buffer: S, delim: T) {
  let result: S[] = [];
  let idx = 0, i = 0;
  result.push(buffer.slice(buffer[i] == delim ? idx : i));
  return result;
}
```

It's also possible to eliminate `T` if you want:

```
export function Parse<S extends Splittable<any>>(buffer: S, delim: S[number]) { ... }
```

Either way you should be getting the behavior you're looking for:

```
const v1: string[] = Parse("121212", "2");
const v2: boolean[][] = Parse([true, false, true], true);
const v3: Buffer[] = Parse(new Buffer(""), 123)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXzgMyhEcDkA7CAEwFMcBuAKAuIA9JY4YBPMYuAIQFc01ioAZYAGtiAHgAqAPjgBeDt15Q4AHzgBnGFGB4A5irjiA2gF1K1OtHjaYfNAEMAxmwDKYADbAYMOwCM3YqUQKOHUPJwAKYEIaAC44PE4QHz4AGjh-PAB+OISkvgBKOJgAC2A1ShDDKNj4xOSoYzjxYLgoYjtCCDw3JnTiXRKcur4KZCpaeng0TjwHGGAuuAAFOyg1YgAmAHF+vmAHNVFnOFobPEI1OFcPL19-CUk0qXCfBT445zSSDxAm-KCQv54G01Jw3DAPiZZHATBU+lZotCAAxpYDIuEgsEwAB0YE4amKLzeUGxajCxCJPD4VWMsjk31AcEycGqcDiwHy+QxxBgnCgeFaxFB4MoY3Mk3QMzmCwFKzWYmOp36Fyu7k83j8YjseCYkkklMUHy+xB+kNy9WM-wQLSBguFEKuULksJtPJZiLkKJZ6JamPBuPxhNeVJJZP2FODihpdLgDOwzNZ7M53N5-LtWNFVAcXQ0cAAbgBGOIaLS6J3LVbrcIAIgLGzrderaWrG2rXIo2bwubzGziPggEH82pM5blVcMmk4xDS9jc6zSk+IxgXUCn7c73YAzHEuCHR5WKXhiAB3eQhmtttJ1zf5KhAA)